# How to (easily) get current file path in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

### How to (easily) get current file path in Sublime Text 3

I don't often use ST console (*I used it only once to install package manager*), but I suppose it could be good way to :

- get current file path like some kind **pwd** command.
- *But it doesn't work.*

---

**Does anyone know an easy way to get current file path?**

- *to clipboard : better not a strict objective in the answer*
- *not necessary by ST command, maybe package?*

Comment: Just if you're curious, in console you get the path using `view.file_name()` and you copy it to clipboard using `sublime.set_clipboard(view.file_name())`

Comment: If you want to *see* the path, just hover your mouse over the tab, and a tooltip with the path will show up.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Right click somewhere in the file (not on the title tab) --> Copy file path

If you don't want to use the mouse, you could set up a keyboard shortcut as explained here https://superuser.com/questions/636057/how-to-set-shortcut-for-copy-file-path-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: Works in sublime text 2 as well. So awesome, yet so simple

Comment: Right clicking images doesn't seem to work though :/

Comment: @aug keyword being 'text' in the name Sublime Text.

Comment: been here before...damn I keep clicking on the title tab to get it

Comment: too bad it's not possible on the tab, you have to switch tab before doing that, sometimes it's a little bit annoying

Comment: Is there a way to show it on screen? (preferably a keyboard shortcut). Reason is because I have many files of the same name in the same directory, and most commonly have stuff I want to keep on the clipboard)

Comment: I just realised hovering over the tab gives the full file path

Answer (score 29):

To easily copy the current file path, add the following to `Key Bindings - User`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+c"], "command": "copy_path" },
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/636057/how-to-set-shortcut-for-copy-file-path-in-sublime-text-3/636175#636175)

`Key Bindings - User` can be opened via the command palette (`command + p` on OSX)

Comment: How do you know that `copy_path` is the right command ? How do we know what available ? Is there any docs that I miss ?

Comment: @ihue - good question; wasn't able to locate `copy_path` in the docs; if you check out the source I provided above, that user turned on command logging via `sublime.log_commands(True)`.

Comment: May be it will help someone: to get back the `Copy path` from command palette add a `Default.sublime-commands` entry as [described in the documentation](https://www.sublimemerge.com/docs/command_palette) with: `[{"caption": "File: Copy path", "command": "copy_path"}]`

Answer (score 22):

Easy to understand using image. On Right Click you will get this.

[image]

Transcribed code in image for convenience:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os

class CopyFilenameCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if len(self.view.file_name()) > 0:
            filename = os.path.split(self.view.file_name())[1]
            sublime.set_clipboard(filename)
            sublime.status_message("Copied file name: %s" % filename)

    def is_enabled(self):
        return self.view.file_name()...  # can't see
```

Answer (score 4):

**Mac OS X - Sublime Text 3**

Right click `>` Copy File Path

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A lot of these answers involve touching the mouse. Here's how to do get the path without any mouse clicks using [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements)

1. Install SideBarEnhancements using PackageControl.
2. Click super + shift + P to open the command palette
3. In the command palette begin typing `path` until you see `File: Copy Path`
4. Select `File: Copy Path`

Now the path to file you are working in is copied into your clipboard.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Antoine in the comments, as of 2024 the package SideBarEnhancements no longer provides this functionality. The [FileManager](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileManager) package is the replacement for SideBarEnhancements. The steps using FileManager are

1. Install FileManager using PackageControl.
2. Click `super + shift + P` to open the command palette
3. In the command palette begin typing `copy path` until you see the FileManager options `FileManager: Copy Path From Root`, `FileManager: Copy Absolute Path`, and `FileManager: Copy Relative Path`
4. Select the option that's right for you.

Comment: As of 2024 unfortunately this plugin [seems to have removed that functionality](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/commit/d6f12d9c37063ca8a86c34e7068627893db76f30)

Comment: Thanks for catching that @Antoine. The package FileManager has the allows the same work flow in the current system.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Sublime Package which gives your current file location inside a status bar. I just cloned them directly to my /sublime-text-3/Packages folder.

```
git clone git@github.com:shagabutdinov/sublime-shell-status.git ShellStatus;

git clone git@github.com:shagabutdinov/sublime-status-message.git StatusMessage;
```

You have to check/read the description on GitHub. Even it is listed in package control it would not install properly for me. You can actually edit the shell output as you want. If you have the right skills with python/shell.

Looks like this (Material Theme)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're like me and always click on items in the sidebar just to realize that copying the path only works when clicking in the editor area, have a look at the [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) package. It has a huge bunch of options to copy file paths in a variety of different ways.

Installation is available via Package Control (despite the webpage only mentions installation via manual download).

**Note:** The package **“sends basic, anonymous statistics”**. The webpage explains how to opt out from that.

[image: SublimeSideBarEnhancementsScreenshot]

Comment: As of 2024 unfortunately this plugin [seems to have removed that functionality](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/commit/d6f12d9c37063ca8a86c34e7068627893db76f30)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [this link](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/file-name-and-full-path-to-clipboard/4833/9). The code in the link is given by [**robertcollier4**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/users/robertcollier4).

Create a file named `CpoyFileName.py` or whatever you like with .py extension.

Save the file in `Sublime Text 3\Packages\User` folder. Then paste the above given key bindings in your `Preferences: Key Bindings` file.

Now, you can use the specified key bindings to copy just filename or total (absolute) filepath.

Please note that the filename or filepath do contain file extension.

Answer (score 1):

### Fastest Solution ( No Packages Needed + Comprehensive ):

Folder Path:

1. Folder in ***"Sidebar"***
2. Right Click
3. ***"Find In Folder"***
4. ***"Where"*** field contains everything you need

File Path:

1. File in current ***"Tab"***
2. Right Click
3. ***"Copy File Path"***